# Wallet not getting loaded with Multibit

Tags: multibit

Why is it giving me this error and not receiving my bit coins?

```
The system cannot find the path specified ".org.multibit.file.WalletSaveException"
Cannot save wallet 'C:\Program Files\MultiBit-0.5.15\null\MultiBit\multibit.wallet'
Created wallet "C:\Program Files\MultiBit-0.5.15\null\MultiBit\multibit.wallet".
Could not load the wallet file "C:\Program Files\MultiBit-0.5.15\null\MultiBit\multibit.wallet".
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout pywallet. Its a python script that may be able to help you out by recovering your private key. I've had similar issues with Multibit in the past. Is your wallet encrypted?

https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet

Answer (score 0):

Check out the trouble shooting page. https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_troubleshooting.html

If you can get to the wallet file in terminal window or file browser, move it to a location that doesn't have null in it. null in a file path seems strange.